# How Can I Run A Code Just Once In Kotlin?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-fragments, android-sqlite

I have a basic knowledge of Kotlin. I'm working on a small application. Since I need a variable in more than one function in my application, I just created a variable under the class and gave a default value to this variable. However, this variable should only work when the application is first opened. Is there a code where I can do this?

```
class Main : Fragment() {

    var numara = 0 //the variable I am talking about


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        zikirCek.text = "${numara}"

        zikirCek.setOnClickListener {
            zikir(it)
        }

        sifirlaButton.setOnClickListener {
            sifirla(it)
        }

        kaydetButton.setOnClickListener {
            kaydetme(it)
        }

        kayitYukle.setOnClickListener {
            kayityukle(it)
        }

        try {

            arguments?.let {

                //numara = mainArgs.fromBundle(it).numara.toInt()
                var secilenId = MainArgs.fromBundle(it).id

                context?.let {

                    val db = it.openOrCreateDatabase("Zikirler", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null)
                    val cursor = db.rawQuery(
                        "SELECT * FROM zikirler WHERE id = ?",
                        arrayOf(secilenId.toString())
                    )

                    val zikirr = cursor.getColumnIndex("zikir")

                    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

                        zikirCek.setText(cursor.getString(zikirr))

                    }

                    cursor.close()

                }
            }

        } catch (e: Exception){
            e.printStackTrace()
        }

    }
```

These are also the functions I mentioned

```
   fun zikir(view: View){

        numara = numara + 1
        zikirCek.text = "${numara}"

    }

    fun sifirla(view: View){

        numara = 0
        zikirCek.text = "${numara}"

    }

    fun kaydetme(view: View){

        val action = MainDirections.actionMainToKaydet(numara)
        Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(action)

    }

    fun kayityukle(view: View){

        val actionn = MainDirections.actionMainToKayityukleme()
        Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(actionn)

    }
}
```

Comment: What does it mean for a variable to "work"?

Comment: I mean, this variable will be read by the android studio just once, then neutralized.

Comment: Your question title might not be the most suitable one.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the variable using `SharedPreferences in Android`:

```
// Prepare a SharedPreference Object.
val sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("preferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

// To save the variable
sharedPreferences.edit().putInt("numara", numara).apply()
    
// To retrieve the variable
val numara = sharedPreferences.getInt("numara", 0)
```

To understand the answer better, I recommend you read [this](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences):

> Interface for accessing and modifying preference data returned by Context#getSharedPreferences. For any particular set of preferences, there is a single instance of this class that all clients share. Modifications to the preferences must go through an Editor object to ensure the preference values remain in a consistent state and control when they are committed to storage.

Comment: I understood what you wanted to tell but I can't use SP in the fragment

Comment: Why can't you...?

Comment: I don't know, android studio not allow